# Efficient way to generate sequence fits multiple constraints

Tags: algorithms

Given two numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a \neq b$, and two constants $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My goal is to generate a set $G$ with $n$ distinct elements that contains both $a, b$ and satisfies the following constraint. ($n$ is not fixed, can be arbitrary)

Denote the number of elements in $G$ that are larger than $a$ or $b$ as $L_a$ or $L_b$, the number of elements in $G$ that are smaller than $a$ or $b$ as $S_a$ or $S_b$.

The constraints are $S_a - L_a = A$ and $S_b - L_b = B$.

Is it possible to achieve it in polynomial time?

Comment: Why sequence? Isn’t $G$ just a set?

Comment: Hmm. So duplicates are allowed?

Comment: Your question specified distinct elements. There is no kind of ordering anywhere, so why isn’t $G$ just a set?

Comment: Ah yes you are right, it should be a set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality $a<b$.  Suppose there are $M$ elements $a<x<b$.  Then $$S_b-S_a=M+1\\
L_a-L_b=M+1$$
The extra $1$ in the first equation counts $a$ which is counted by neither $S_a$ nor $M$, and the $1$ in the second equation counts $b$.  So we have $$S_b-S_a=L_a-L_b\\
(B+L_b)-(A+L_a)=L_a-L_b\\B-A=2(L_a-L_b)$$
so that $B_A$ must be even and positive.  If this is so, then $M=\frac{B-A}2-1$.

Choose any $M$ numbers between $a$ and $b$.

Choose some arbitrary number $L_b$ numbers $>b$ and choose $S_a=L_b+\frac{B+A}2$ numbers $<a$.

Then $$S_b=S_a+M+1=\left(L_b+\frac{B+A}2\right)+\left(\frac{B-A}2-1\right)+1=L_b+B$$
and $$\begin{align}
L_a&=L_b+M+1\\
&=L_b+\frac{B-A}2\\
&=S_a-\frac{B+A}2+\frac{B-A}2\\
&=S_a-A
\end{align}$$

If $n$ is given, note that $$\begin{align}
n&=S_a+M+L_b+2\\
&=2L_b+\frac{B+A}2+\frac{B_A}2-1+2\\
&=2L_b+B+1
\end{align}$$ so $n-1-B$ must be even, and we must take $$L_b=\frac{n-1-B}2$$

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there’s a linear complexity way to generate the $G$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right